# Transactions work, but throw errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a use case in my application where I need to perform an update on two nodes in the database, where the the update being performed itself depends on data that is read from both of those nodes.  The code I wrote to do this does have the desired effect on the database, but the logs contain the error:

```
Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

Here is some minimal code needed to reproduce the error.  If the database initially has numerical entries at paths "b" and "c", and then a new value is written at "a", the below code will update b and c but will report the above error in the logs.

```
exports.bork = functions.database.ref("a").onWrite(event => {
  return Promise.all([
    admin.database().ref("b").once("value"),
    admin.database().ref("c").once("value")
]).then(snapshots => {
  var left = snapshots[0].val();
  var right = snapshots[1].val();
  var average = (left + right) / 2;
  return Promise.all([
    admin.database().ref("b").transaction(
      data => { return data + average; }
    ),
    admin.database().ref("c").transaction(
      data => { return data + average; }
    )
  ]);
});
}
);
```

I'm quite sure what is causing this.  It only seems to happen when I transact on a node after reading it, but I don't see why that should be a problem.  Is there a way of performing this update that avoids this error?

Edit:  As requested, I have stripped down my above example as much as possible.  It still produces the same error.

```
exports.bork = functions.database.ref("a").onWrite(event => {
  return admin.database().ref("b").once("value")
  .then(snapshots => {
    return admin.database().ref("b").transaction(
        data => { return data; }
      );
  });
});
```

On the other hand, the below code works fine in a web page.

```
Promise.all([
      database.ref("b").once("value"),
      database.ref("c").once("value")
    ]).then(snapshots => {
      console.log("Acquired snapshots.");
      var left = snapshots[0].val();
      var right = snapshots[1].val();
      var average = (left + right) / 2;
      return database.ref("b").transaction(
        data => { return data + average; }
      );
    }).then( result=>{console.log(result)}, error=>{console.log(error)} )
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what would cause that error. Two questions for that: 1) Does the error also appear if you run the same flow in a local node.js process (or even in a web page)? 2) Can you reduce the code to see what precise statement causes the error?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @FrankvanPuffelen. The error does not appear when running the equivalent code in a webpage. I have edited my post to contain the web client code I used to test this, as well as a shorter database example that causes the same problem. The only way I could get the code to run without error was to remove the entire transaction on b.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, but can you give the same code a spin in a node.js process? There you'd be using our Admin SDK, so if it fails there I know who to bug. :-)